# Sentry On-Premise cannot create a superuser

Tags: docker, sentry

When I follow the instructions: https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise, I failed in the third step.`docker-compose run --rm web upgrade`, Its prompt is as follows:

`Running migrations for sentry:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for sentry.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for nodestore:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for nodestore.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for search:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for search.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for social_auth:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for social_auth.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for jira_ac:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for jira_ac.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for hipchat_ac:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for hipchat_ac.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Creating missing DSNs
Correcting Group.num_comments counter`

I tried a lot of ways and still didn't solve it.

Comment: I tried to create a user with ```docker-compose run --rm web createuser```, it work.  But I got another error, ```IndexError: list index out of range```.

Comment: did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

I follow steps under this issue, and it resolves your new issue

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/8862

```
docker-compose run --rm web shell

from sentry.models import Project
from sentry.receivers.core import create_default_projects
create_default_projects([Project])
```